# Installing txMYSQL on Python

Tags: python, mysql, twisted

I am trying to establish MYSQL connection with my twisted server script. I found out that txMYSQL is a good choice to use, I dowloaded the package out of [Github](https://github.com/hybridlogic/txMySQL) and tried installing from the setup.py file, but it didn't work.

I tried inslalling txMYSQL by using `easy_install txmysql` but it dosen't appear to be found through this command since its not on pythons server.

**How can I install txMYSQL ?**

I am currently using python 2.7.8 on my Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install using `pip` and referencing Github repo. I tried here and worked well on a Ubuntu 12.04.4

```
pip install git+https://github.com/hybridlogic/txMySQL.git
```

Comment: did this answer work? does txmysql work?  it looks like it hasn't been touched in quite some time.